# QGIS: Making a heatmap which doesn't look at point density

Tags: qgis, heat-map

I have a file of postcodes (x and y co-ords, and a percent value for what I'm measuring).
In some areas there are a lot of postcodes, in others very few.

I can use the heatmap option in properties>symbology. Easy enough to set up, and weight by my percentage value.

But, when I see the results, it seems that it is taking more account of the density of postcodes than it is of the actual percentage values I want to heatmap. So some areas look to have a very low value on the heatmap, despite having consistently high percentages for the few points in that area.

So, how do I make a heatmap that purely refers to the percentage field, and doesn't weight for point density?

Comment: Density belongs to kernel density estimation that is 
often called as heatmap  https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/interpolation.html
Try to draw a sketch or find an example about the result that you would like to get. Maybe someone can then suggest a suitable method for you.

Comment: Make the radius of the heat map bigger - see also https://xkcd.com/1138/